# How to save the output [summary(model)] of generalized linear model as a .csv file in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write or export the output/result from a GLM but I keep getting an error message. My data has both continuous (numeric) and categorical (factor) variables. Would I need to specify which variable are which before I run the model?

Here is the code I used:

```
library(dplyr)
setwd("F://Aug 2019") 
cg <- read.csv("GZLM_CG.csv")
names(cg) 
str(cg)

#####GLiMs#######

model1 <- glm(weight ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 + Var5, data=cg)
summary(model1)
write.csv(model1,file='GZLM_CG_M1_result.csv')
```

With this code:

```
write.csv(model1,file='GZLM_CG_M1_result.csv')
```

I get the following error message:

> ```
> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
>   cannot coerce class ‘c("glm", "lm")’ to a data.frame
> ```

I can't find a fix but I'm sure it must be real simple. I expect to have .csv file created with the output from summary(model1) but instead I get the error message above. Thank you in advance.

So here is the output from summary(model1)

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2676  -0.9872   0.1245   0.9605   2.7419  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         7.573e-01  3.576e-01   2.118 0.034194 *  
Var1                2.375e-02  3.570e-02   0.665 0.505869    
Var2               -2.042e-04  6.059e-05  -3.370 0.000752 ***
Var3               -8.885e-02  3.300e-03  -26.927  < 2e-16 ***
Var4                4.629e-01  5.077e-01   0.912 0.361913    
Var5_1              1.169e-01  2.612e-01   0.448 0.654348    
Var5_2              1.887e+00  2.970e-01   6.353 2.11e-10 ***
Var5_3              1.324e+00  2.907e-01   4.555 5.23e-06 ***
Var5_4              9.305e-01  2.625e-01   3.545 0.000392 ***
Var5_5              -5.847e-01  2.740e-01  -2.134 0.032815 *  
Var5_6              9.736e-01  7.220e-01   1.348 0.177531    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 12441  on 8973  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 10540  on 8963  degrees of freedom
AIC: 10562

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47149822/10580543 check this answer of a related question using the package `broom`

Comment: `write.csv` is for tabular data. A model object or `summary` output is not tabular data.

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't really make sense: how do you expect your model to be represented in a comma-separated format? In other words, what should the model look like when opened in Excel? Look up the `broom` package to extract key info from a model in tabular format. If you want to save the model (and not merely some model info) in order to re-use it later, save it in an RDS file which can contain arbitrary R objects.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have edited my question to include the output. What I want is for the coefficients to be written/saved as a table as .csv or in excel. Hope that explains what I am trying to do (rather than copy and paste each output).

Answer (score 1):

You can't save it like that but I am assuming you want the original weight values, fitted weight values and residuals. If yes then you can do as follows.

```r
model1 <- glm(weight ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 + Var5, data=cg) 
Temp_df <- data.frame(cg$weight, model1$fitted.values, model1$residuals)
write.csv(Temp_df,file='GZLM_CG_M1_result.csv')
```

Please let me know if you wanted something else.

Edited in response to comment.

---

From the line where it says "Coefficients:" ..till the line "Var5_6 9.736e-01 7.220e-01 1.348 0.177531" .. just before dashes(----), there is "some" hope of casting it into a csv (comma separated values) but after that all hopes come crashing down as the pattern is lost. There are no columns any more that can be parsed. However if you are concerned about that "hope" part, here is what you can do.

```r
model1 <- glm(weight ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3 + Var4 + Var5, data=cg) 
write.csv(summary(model1)['coefficients'],file='GZLM_CG_M1_result.csv')
```

I think this is as far as I can see

Comment: Thank you - but no, this is not what I want to. I have edited my question to clarify my doubt. Sorry for not making this clearer earlier.

Comment: @EleMan I have edited my response.

Comment: Thank you @Amit, that was what I wanted! Now, I would like to know why it would not be possible to save the entire output to a table? If as you say only there is no 'pattern', certainly at least the Deviance Residuals also has a table format, if not in the same structure like the coefficients table - why does R not produce outputs like SPSS does? Just curious - thanks

Comment: @EleMan There are ways to save the entire output and yes Deviance Residuals also has a table format. I am on mobile so scrolling up and down, I have missed that. I am not familiar with SPSS but R stores a variety of information about models and results. I would suggest to look at the documentation to get started for a particular model. Google and Stackoverflow are your best friends, in case you get stuck somewhere. All the best.